# (com.mysema.maven:apt- maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources)

Tags: java, querydsl

I am also facing the same issue. But I want to mention my issues over here.
So below are my issues:

1. in `pom.xml`:

   ```
   <goals>
       <goal>process</goal>
   </goals>
   ```

   when I comment out this block, everything works as expected. But with this block an error in `pom.xml` occurs and says

   > You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the class path. If this occurs during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well (com.mysema.maven:apt- maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources)
2. The Q Object is not getting generated for my entity class.

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: What is "the same issue"? Can you add a question to your post?

Comment: Below is my issue:Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) on project QueryDslProj_1: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well